# SQLAlchemy defers loading updated_at column when using mapper events

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy model defined which contains an updated_at attribute:

`updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.now(), onupdate=db.func.now())`

I have a couple of mapper events defined on the model as well:

```
@listens_for(Drive, 'after_insert')
def insert_listener(mapper, connect, self):
    from api.drive import operations
    operations.after_create(self)


@listens_for(Drive, 'after_update')
def update_listener(mapper, connect, self):
    from api.drive import operations
    operations.after_update(self)
```

I am uploading the model as a json to a document store in the `after_create` and `after_update` routines.

I am noticing that SQLAlchemy doesn't load the update_at attribute unless explicitly queried for in the `after_*` routines, and as a result, the updated_at timestamp never makes it to the document store. If I log `model.updated_at` right before uploading the object, it works fine. I haven't configured deferred loading of this attribute in the model definition, but SQLAlchemy seems to be doing so under the covers.

Comment: You configured the attributes as **database functions**, so only when the data has been committed to the database and then is read back will you see the results.

Comment: Consider using a Python object instead, such as `default=datetime.datetime.now` and `onupdate=datetime.datetime.now`, and use separate `server_default` and `server_onupdate` entries if you also need this to happen on the database server (e.g. when you have other software that also uses the same database and you want to ensure those columns are kept up-to-date with database-server-side defaults).

Answer (score 4):

The `after_insert` and `after_update` events are there to run *additional* actions when the session flushes transient objects to the database. At this stage the data is flowing in *one* direction, from Python to the database. Any database-side triggers such as your defaults are not visible at this stage, unless the server explicitly supports returning such data and you configured SQLAlchemy to retrieve them at that time.

Just in case this isn't clear: `func.now()` is the SQLAlchemy spelling for the `NOW()` function in SQL, the function is executed as the database executes the `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statements, so the value only exists on the database side. They are [*Client-Invoked SQL Expressions*](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/defaults.html#client-invoked-sql-expressions).

You should use [`server_default`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.server_default) and [`server_onupdate`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.server_onupdate) instead. If you are using a database that supports the `RETURNING` or `OUTPUT inserted` or similar features to return expression values from inserts or updates directly when executing (such as PostgreSQL, Oracle, and SQL Server) then such values will be available to SQL-Alchemy immediately. For MySQL or SQLLite or other databases without `RETURNING` support you are forced to refresh teh object  See [*Fetching Server-Generated Defaults*](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/persistence_techniques.html#fetching-server-generated-defaults).

For a server that supports `RETURNING` I think adding `eager_defaults` should be enough:

```
class SomeModel(Base):
    updated_at = db.Column(
        db.DateTime,
        server_default=db.func.now(),
        server_onupdate=db.func.now()
    )

    __mapper_args__ = {"eager_defaults": True}
```

(The `server_onupdate` line really only means that SQLAlchemy will know to look for an updated value, and probably requires an addinional trigger definition to work. See [this issue where `server_onupdate` is used with MySQL](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/3444/sqlalchemy-does-not-emit-server_onupdate)).

Even when the database doesn't support `RETURNING`, using `eager_defaults` should work as that'll automatically add an additional `SELECT` to the query. *This does cost you in terms of performance*. Consider using [Python callables for your defaults](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/defaults.html#python-executed-functions) instead (and forgo having the database take care of these values).